# SQL RIGHT JOIN on Subquery isn't working

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have two tables containing over a million rows each. The two tables look something this like this;
Table1

```
student_id     student_name
001            mark
002            moses
003            mike
004            john
005            jeff
006            joe
```

and
Table2

```
student_id   height   weight
001          170      80      
002          130      88
003          190      90
004          150      75
005          200      85
006          180      78
```

What is want to is to return students with top 4 weights if their height is between 150cm and 200cm; something like this

```
student_id      student_name         weight
003             mike                 90 
005             jeff                 85
001             mark                 80
006             joe                  78
```

I have tried with something like this but it doesn't work;

```
SELECT a.student_id AS `Student ID`, a.student_name AS `Student Name`, b.weight
FROM table1 AS a
RIGHT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT student_id 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE height BETWEEN 150 AND 200 ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 4
    ) AS b
ON b.student_id
WHERE a.student_id IN b.student_id
```

Any approach that achieves the required result is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ON condition seems to be wrong

Comment: Why do you think RIGHT JOIN is needed here?  Outer join (LEFT/RIGHT) is used if you want to return rows from one table that does not have a match in the other table.  AFAICT, that is not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

I use SQL Server but I suppose this should work...

```
SELECT table2.student_id as 'Student ID',
       table1.student_name AS 'Student Name', 
       table2.weight
FROM table2 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.student_id = table2.student_id 
WHERE table2.height BETWEEN 150 AND 200 
ORDER BY table2.weight DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron... didin't know how to breaklines. It's a lot better!

Answer (score 0):

I would have used a `LEFT JOIN` IE

```
SELECT a.student_id, a.student_name, b.weight 
FROM table1 a
  LEFT JOIN table2 b
  ON a.student_id = b.student_id
WHERE b.hieght 
   BETWEEN 150 
   AND 200 
ORDER BY b.weight DESC LIMIT 4;
```